# Unit test imports, with imports isolation

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, mocking

I have a python package that uses dev and prod libraries.
I want to make sure that some files in that package never import any dev libraries, as these files are used for deployment
and should only import prod libraries.

For instance, I would like a unit test that fails with the `my_package.__init__.py` file as shown below, but succeeds if we remove the dev library import.

```py
import libraries.prod 
import libraries.dev
```

[image]

It's easy to make a **independent test** that satifies those conditions, and expectedly fails on the dev imports `my_package.__init__.py` while succeeding otherwise, for instance:

```py
 def test_dev_libraries_not_imported_in_package_init(): 
     with mock.patch.dict(sys.modules): 
         import_module("my_package") 
         assert "libraries.dev" not in sys.modules
```

However, when running the full unit tests suite, for instance with pytest, this test can fail.
This happens if there is another unit test in the same suite that runs some tests against the dev library, for instance:

```py
 def test_dev_libraries(): 
     import_module("libraries.dev") 
     assert "libraries.dev" in sys.modules
```

Ideally, I would like both tests to be able to coexist in the same unit_tests directory, but it seems like imports are all loaded together at the beginning of all tests. I was wondering if there was a way to isolate that?

I've seen a few related issues that mock the sys.module object but it didn't help: running independently the test works fine, but not running is at the test suite level.

I created a small repository for reproducibility:

https://github.com/Edouard360/unit-test-imports-with-imports-isolation/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So rather than modifying all of the surrounding tests, I think you can modify your one isolated test case to make sure you're getting the desired effect. If you delete from the `sys.modules` dict prior to the import, you'll still be testing the same outcome while controlling the isolated case. I was going to suggest `del` here, but `clear` might be even more appropriate if you want to simulate a blank slate:

```
def test_dev_libraries_not_imported_in_package_init(): 
    with mock.patch.dict(sys.modules): 
        sys.modules.clear()  # or del sys.modules['libraries.dev']
        import_module("my_package") 
        assert "libraries.dev" not in sys.modules
```

EDIT: Here's a little isolated example I came up with using the `import json`:

```
import sys

from importlib import import_module
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch.dict(sys.modules):
    sys.modules.clear()
    print(sys.modules.keys())
    import_module('json')
    print(sys.modules.keys())

print(sys.modules.keys())
```

Running it shows that you go from a blank slate to the modules required for a json import, and back to the original imported modules of all of your tests' imports.